# How to divide a col-md-12 correctly in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns :

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-4></div>
  <div class="col-md-8></div>
</div>
```

Now the "col-md-4" column I have to divide in 7 equals columns.

How can I do that ?

Comment: I think you have to modify the default 12 column layout as it is not possible to divide 12 with 7. But what about a simple table in your column? Would that be suitable? As long as you do not need responsive behaviour within it could be a idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this and enlarge `width` of `.col-md-1` like you want. You'll get you `.col-md-4` divided in 7 equals columns.

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="col-md-4>
         <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
         <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
         <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
         <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
         <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
         <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
         <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">2</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the default 12 column layout

```
<style>
  .newcol-md-1 {
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 float: left;
 width: 14.285714285714286%;
 }
 </style>

 <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="col-md-4>
     <div class="newcol-md-1">1</div>
     <div class="newcol-md-1">1</div>
     <div class="newcol-md-1">1</div>
     <div class="newcol-md-1">1</div>
     <div class="newcol-md-1">1</div>
     <div class="newcol-md-1">1</div>
     <div class="newcol-md-1">1</div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">2</div>
</div>
```